# Can we change root view controller as a Storybord After creating a project in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode11

I had try following

1. Replace following code in SceneDelegate

   ```
   let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
   window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
   self.window = window
   window.makeKeyAndVisible()
   ```

instead

```
guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
```

also set Main Interface as a Storyboard and entry point.

> Issue : Getting black screen after launch Launching screen

Comment: You'll get more and better answers if you clarify your question. Don't assume we know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using Xcode 11 beta 3, I can reliably get a storyboard working as the root view controller in a new SwiftUI project with the following steps:

1. Comment out the code in SceneDelegate's `scene(willConnectTo:)` function.
2. Create a new Main.storyboard, add a view controller, and set "Is Initial View Controller" on it.
3. Select the Info.plist for the iOS target, right click Open As -> Source Code.
4. Add the `UISceneStoryboardFile` and `UIMainStoryboardFile` keys as shown here:

[image: Info.plist snippet]

Setting the Main Interface in the Target's Deployment Info section only sets the `UIMainStoryboardFile` key but I had to set both in order to get it to work properly.

Here is the full code of the Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
                    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I added the full Info.plist.